# Can not access control panel

Tags: windows-vista, control-panel

I can not access Contol panel in my windows vista machine.

As soon as i click the "conrol panel" item in start items, it shows up a window and then its closed automatically ( same happens if i use "control" command).

Is there some program or some registry entry thats restricting it? is ther a way to control this behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like you have a bit of a malware problem.  You should scan your PC.  Also, http://superuser.com is better suited for these types of questions specific to a PC.

Comment: Considering both this and your other question, you very likely have malware of some sort on your computer.  As the previous commenter suggested, you should scan your computer and (hopefully) eliminate the virus without having to back up important files and reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you caught yourself a pretty nasty case of malware. Malware programs will often times hack destroy functionality in windows to block the user from doing things that might get rid of the Malware (in your case, preventing you from using System Restore).

If you can get a connection to the internet you could try to download/install [MalwareBytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) and see if that'll get rid of it.

Don't be surprised if ctrl-alt-delete doesn't work anymore. If your internet connection starts doing 'funny things' like playing audio advertisements over the speakers. If you can't install anti-malware because the installer fails. If your anti-virus starts throwing random errors and crashing.

The malware coders are crafty devils these days.

If you can't get rid of it, you'll probably have to wipe and reload the OS.